# Why do I declare properties twice? or do I?

Tags: objective-c

Sorry for the kind of useless post title, but since I'm not really sure what I am doing, that was the best i could come up with.

In my header file it looks like this

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
NSMutableArray *eventsArray;    
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *eventsArray;

@end
```

This is not all the properties but i removed all but one for simplicity.

I'm doing this by following a guide from apple developer. It seems as though the guide is not totally updated since it tells me to synthesize properties, wich i should not have to anymore right?

Anyways, why is it like this? To me, a beginner at this, it seems as though I declare the property twice? Or do I do something else at the first row there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's like this for historical reasons, with the older compiler.

You can do this nowadays:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *eventsArray;

@end
```

The way you have it, you are declaring an instance attribute, and then you are saying you want to automatically generate getters and setters.

Nowadays, you can just say you have a property and the compiler will automatically generate the instance attribute at compile time. It removes the apparent redundancy.

Comment: You might want to point out that an instance variable and a property are two quite different things. A declared property is an abstraction that represents an accessor method or method pair that may or may not rely on an underlying instance variable for storage.

Answer (score 2):

> To me, a beginner at this, it seems as though I declare the property
>   twice? Or do I do something else at the first row there?

A property and the instance variable that backs it up (if there is one) are two different things. A property is really just a promise that the class provides certain accessor methods. So the fact that you had to declare the property and ivar separately isn't strange. However, most properties are, in fact, backed by an ivar with a related name, and writing and maintaining the two separately got to be a chore. So Apple added ivar synthesis to the compiler, so that the compiler generates an ivar for any synthesized properties for which an ivar doesn't already exist. Also, because synthesized accessors are by far the most common, and because the compiler will use any accessors that you provide even if a property is marked `@synthesize`, that became the default so that you no longer need the compiler directive.